# C# xml-rpc <dateTime.iso8601>

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, xml-rpc

so I have to hit a webservice (xml-rpc), im using xml-rpc.net library to do this. One of the parameters i have to pass must be of type  of which there is no such thing in .net as a variable. At the moment i am just writing the XML and posting, this is not a satisfiable solution.

How the xml for the datetime looks:

```
</param>
<param>
  <value>
    <dateTime.iso8601>20101117T09:42:00</dateTime.iso8601>
  </value>
</param>
<param>
```

anyone got any smart ideas, someone said make a variable of a class dateTime.iso8601 and use that as the parameter type.

Comment: are you sure xml-rpc.net will not automatically serialize your `DateTime` in the appropriate format?

Comment: I will test it next week and update

Answer (score 2):

xml-rpc.net certainly takes a System.Datetime and converts to dateTime.iso8601. A gotcha I had was with the various interpretations of dateTime.iso8601. From your xml template, your datetime output is supported (20101117T09:42:00) and you won't have the same problem. I had a very strict upstream server that wanted some offset (e.g +001) and I had to extend and pass a datetime format to xml-rpc.net.

**Edit**

Yea I modified the code to achieve the new DateTimeFormat. I downloaded the source and made the following modifications (I wish it was better hosted and one could offer a modification).

There is an XmlRpcSerializer.cs, which is where the serialization of the type to xml-rpc format happens. The method you need is naturally...

```
void Serialize(
      XmlWriter xtw,
      Object o,
      MappingActions mappingActions,
      List<object> nestedObjs)
```

Somewhere in this method, is a check for XmlRpcType.tDateTime:

```
else if (xType == XmlRpcType.tDateTime)
        {
          DateTime dt = (DateTime)o;
          //The following line is what you need, if a custom DateTime format was supplied, to override the default
          string sdt = dt.ToString((string.IsNullOrEmpty(DateTimeFormat) ? "yyyyMMdd'T'HH':'mm':'ss" : DateTimeFormat),
          DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
          WriteFullElementString(xtw, "dateTime.iso8601", sdt);
        }
```

The rest of the story is how to pass the custom datetime format to the XmlRpcSerializer class. You could just add a property to this class to make it happen. There is an XmlRpcFormatSettings that could be used but that's up to you.

Comment: How did you "extend and pass a datetime format to xml-rpc.net."?

Comment: Hope that is what you're looking for?

Comment: I'am using XML-RPC.NET Version 3.0.0 and I cannot use proxy.DateTimeFormat
So I think you changed the source code.

Comment: @RobJanssen I provided some source that should help. I also removed my comment which was not very valid. Basically, the idea is to get a datetime format somehow to the XmlRpcSerializer class. Once the format gets to the class, the modification was to the serialize method which applies the format if available.